# If all iterations return empty do something and if 1 of the iterations returns something do something else

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, axios

I have an array of values, I need to loop through those to run a function based on a value I get from a textbox.

My code:

```
<label for="truck">Truck:</label>
<input type="text" id="truck" name="truck">
<button type="button" id="myButton">Click Me!</button>

const truckBtn = document.getElementById("myButton");
const truckID = document.getElementById("truck");
truckBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

  let arrs = ["one", "two", "three"];

  for (const arr of arrs) {
     axiosFunction(arr, truckID.value).then(d=> {
      console.log(d.data);
      if (d.data.length > 0) {
         // do something
      } else alert("Not Found");
   });
  }
});
```

So `d.data` if `truckID.value` matches what I need the response is:

```
[]
[]
[{...}]
```

That's when it goes into the `if` statement.

The else is when:

if `truckID.value` does not match what I need the response is:

```
[]
[]
[]
```

My issue is when I have the `else`, it goes to the else even when there is match. Is there way to write an if statement when the length of the array is greater than 0 for at least 1 iteration? And do the else if all the iterations return a length of 0?

Comment: Based on your title, I would look into using [Array.some()\(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: @mykaf That's complicated by the fact that it's calling an async function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be ideal if you could rewrite the API behind your `axiosFunction` to take all three `arr` values and return a batch, so you're not making multiple round-trips. But assuming you can't do that, and you're okay with waiting for all the round-trips to return (otherwise you can't know whether they all returned empty), you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait until they're all resolved.

```
<label for="truck">Truck:</label>
<input type="text" id="truck" name="truck">
<button type="button" id="myButton">Click Me!</button>

truckBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

  let arrs = ["one", "two", "three"];
  Promise.all(arrs.map(arr => axiosFunction(arr, truckID.value)))
    .then(results => {
      console.log(results.map(d => d.data)); // [[], [], [...]]
      const firstValidResult = results.find(d => d.data.length > 0);
      if(firstValidResult) {
         // do something with firstValidResult.data
      } else alert("Not Found");
    });
});
```

This code uses `find` assuming you're only expecting one valid result. You could tweak it to use `filter` if there might be several.

Answer (score 1):

Make the callback an async function so you can use `await`. Then you can set a variable based on whether any of the calls return something.

```js
truckBtn.addEventListener("click", async() => {
  let arrs = ["one", "two", "three"];
  let found = false;
  for (const arr of arrs) {
    let d = await axiosFunction(arr, truckID.value);
    console.log(d.data);
    if (d.data.length > 0) {
      found = true;
      // do stuff
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    console.log("Not found!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This also depends on how you intend on looping through the array - do want to:

- operate on the first match only, or
- operate on every match

Your example can be extended by using `break` once you find the match:

```js
const truckBtn = document.getElementById("myButton");
const truckID = document.getElementById("truck");

truckBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let arrs = ["one", "two", "three"];

  for (const arr of arrs) {
     axiosFunction(arr, truckID.value).then(d=> {
      console.log(d.data);
      if (d.data.length > 0) {
         // do something
         break; // don't perform anymore work once we have any match
      } else alert("Not Found");
   });
  }
});
```

Notice the `break` inside the condition when the match is found - this will prevent any subsequent calls to `axiosFunction`, which may or may not be what you want.

Below are a few ways of handling the calls depending on whether you want to wait for each call, get the first matching result, or get all the matching results, using `async / await` and `Array.map`:

```js
const arrs = ["one", "two", "three"];

// execute axiosFunction calls in sequence, like using a for loop
truckBtn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const matches = arrs.map(async x => await axiosFunction(x, truckID.value))
        .filter(x => x.data.length > 0);
  const match = matches.find(Boolean); // get the first truthy result

  // do something if match is not null
}


// execute all axiosFunction calls in parallel
truckBtn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const promises = arrs.map(x => axiosFunction(x, truckID.value));
  // get all matches
  const matches = await Promise.all(promises)
                    .filter(x => x.data.length > 0);
  const match = matches.find(Boolean); // get the first truthy result

  // do something if match is not null
}

// execute axiosFunction calls in parallel, waiting for the first to resolve
truckBtn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const promises = arrs.map(x => axiosFunction(x, truckID.value));
  const firstResolved = await Promise.race(promises);
  const match = firstResolved.data.length > 0 ? firstResolved : null;

  // do something with match
});

// execute axiosFunction calls in parallel, handling if none of them resolve
truckBtn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const promises = arrs.map(x => axiosFunction(x, truckID.value));
  let match = null;

  try {
    const firstResolved = await Promise.any(promises);
    match = firstResolved.data.length > 0 ? firstResolved : match;
  } catch (err) {
    // no promise resolved
  }
  
  // do something with match
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are making multiple requests with `axiosFunction`, you first need to resolve those [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), using [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) or [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Then, you can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check the returned data, and it looks like you need to nest two of them as your result is an array that contains more arrays.

Here's an example with a mocked `axiosFunction`. Type `foo` in the input field for one result, or something else for "not found":

```js
const searchButton = document.getElementById("searchButton");
const truckInput = document.getElementById("truckInput");

const items = ["one", "two", "three"];

function axiosFunction(array, value) {
  return Promise.resolve({
    data: value === 'foo' ? array.map((_, i) => [{}]) : array.map(_ => []),
  })
}

searchButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const { value } = truckInput;
 
  // Make all requests in parallel:
  const promises = items.map((item) => {
    return axiosFunction(items, value)
  })
  
  // Wait for all of them to resolve:
  const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
  
  // Extract the data part from the results:
  const resultsData = results.map(result => result.value.data);
  
  console.log(resultsData);
  
  // Iterate over the data from each request:
  const found = resultsData.some((resultData) => {
    // Itereate over the array items returned by each request:
    return resultData.some((resultItem) => {
      // And check if any of them contains something:
      return resultItem.length > 0;
    });
  })
  
  if (found) {
    alert("Found!");
  } else {
    alert("Not Found...");
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="truck">Truck:</label>
<input type="text" id="truckInput">
<button type="button" id="searchButton">Search</button>
```